# Xamarin AssetManager FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, assets

I've tried opening an asset like mentioned in the [Xamarin Tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/#Reading_Assets)
Unfortunately, I always get a `FileNotFoundException`.

This is code in my Activity:

```
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(assets.Open("test.xml")))
{
     //...
}
```

The build action of `test.xml` is set to `AndroidAsset`.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `test.xml` in the `Assets` directory? i.e. not the root of the project, or in some other directory...

Comment: hey @SushiHangover yes, it lies in the Assets directory

Comment: Uninstall the app from the device & Clean & Rebuild your project & reinstall the app.

Comment: @sJy: I'm surprised but this actually worked :o I could have sworen that I'd tried that before :)

Comment: Sometimes the changes won't get compiled while running the app & a Clean & Rebuild will ensure that.